# Hibernate mappings

Tags: hibernate, foreign-keys

I have the following two relationships

A student can be a part of one school
A school can have many students

For this I have defined the following relationships

```
Class School

@JsonProperty
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="school",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@SortNatural
SortedSet<Student> students;




Class Student
@ManyToOne
School school;
```

The database shows that the table School has null values for student_id column. Why is this so?

Comment: Show us the student_id mapping and also how do you perform the save.Thanks

Comment: I dont have the student-id mapping explicitly set

Comment: school cannot have student_id in this case. Student cant have school_id

Comment: right thats what I wuld expect